# How to calculate distance from a single point along multiple linear features

Tags: qgis, distance, network

I have a discontinuous hydrographic network (line feature) for which I have used the "Points along Geometry" tool to generate points every 200m. I would like to know the distance that separates each of these points from an origin point following the shape of the network.

This is a simplified schematic of the result I would like to obtain :
[image: Ideal situation]

I have ruled out the distance matrix because from my understanding it does not calculate the distance along the lines but rather the shortest distance between the points and the origin.

This is what I have been able to get using the "Line locate Point" function :

[image]

[image]

[image]

It is getting somewhat closer to what I need but it still does not properly calculate distances as highlighted in red.

Can I get the "Line locate Point" function to do what I want or should I look in another direction ?

I have currently no clue as to how to solve my problem.

I am working on QGIS 3.22.

Comment: If you wish to also ask about ArcGIS Pro please do that in a separate question.